# How to get the first Char from the first element of a list using kotlin?

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I want to get to the first Char from the first element of a list or an array example:

```
val myList = arrayOf(
                 "myFirstElement",
                 "mySecondElement")
```

> i tried this : **myList[0][0]** 
>   and this **myList[0].first()** but it does not work

Comment: It works, check it here: https://pl.kotl.in/xRsmTe8Lo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of a couple of extension functions that Kotlin provides to do this quite elegantly, assuming you *know* that the array will have at leastone item and it will have a first character:

```
myArray.first().first()
```

Breaking it down:

1. We have an array (which I've renamed from myList to myArray to
   reduce confusion)
2. We call the [extension function called `first()` on `Array`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html), which gives us the first element of the Array, which is a `String`.
3. We call the [extension function called `first()` on `CharSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/first.html) (which `String` implements), which gives us the
   first character of the `String`.

**However**: If you want to guard against the possibility that the array does not contain anything, you can use the `Array.firstOrNull()` and `CharSequence.firstOrNull()` extensions instead, along with the safe-traversal operator:

```
myArray.firstOrNull()?.firstOrNull()
```

Comment: was just about to comment that you should instead be using firstOrNull :) will upvote your answer

Comment: Ha! Beat you by a second I bet! :)

Comment: i literally saw your edit after I tried it in android studio first xD need to leave some easy questions to answer for me :P

Answer (score 0):

val myList = arrayOf(
            "myFirstElement",
            "mySecondElement")

myList[0].toCharArray()[0]

or

myList[0][0]

> both worked for me